# How to defer "file" function execution in puppet 3.7

Tags: puppet

This seems like a trivial question, but in fact it isn't. I'm using puppet 3.7 to deploy and configure artifacts from my project on to a variety of environments. Puppet 5.5 upgrade is on the roadmap, but without an ETA so far.

One of the things I'm trying to automate is the incremental changes to the underlying db. It's not SQL so standard tools are out of question. These changes will come in the form of shell scripts contained in a special module, that will also be deployed as an artifact. For each release we want to have a file, whose content will list the shell scripts to execute in scope of this release. For instance, if in version 1.2 we had implemented JIRA-123, JIRA-124 and JIRA-125, I'd like to execute scripts JIRA-123.sh, JIRA-124.sh and JIRA-125.sh, but no other ones that will still be in that module from previous releases.

So my  release "control" file would be called something like jiras.1.2.csv and have one line looking like this:

```
JIRA-123,JIRA-124,JIRA-125
```

The task for puppet here seems trivial - read the content of this file, split on "," character, and go on to build exec tasks for each of the jiras. The problem is that the puppet function that should help me do it

```
file("/somewhere/in/the/filesystem/jiras.1.2.csv")
```

gets executed at the time of building the puppet catalog, not at the time when the catalog is applied. However, since this file is a part of the payload of the release, it's not there yet. It will be downloaded from nexus in a tar.gz package of the release and extracted later. I have an anchor I can hold on to, which I use to synchronize the exec tasks, but can I attach the reading of the file content to that anchor?

Maybe I'm approaching the problem incorrectly? I was thinking the module with the pre-implementation and post-implementation tasks that constitute the incremental db upgrades could be structured so that for each release there's a subdirectory matching the version name, but then I need to list the contents of that subdirectory to build my exec tasks, and that too - at least to my limited puppet knowledge - can't be deferred until a particular anchor.

--- EDITED after one of the comments ---

The problem is that the upgrade to puppet 5.x is beyond my control - it's another team handling this stuff in a huge organisation, so I have no influence over that and I'm stuck on 3.7 for the foreseeable future.

As for what I'm trying to do - for a bunch of different software packages that we develop and release I want to create three new ones: pre-implementation, post-implementation and checks. The first will hold any tasks that are performed prior to releasing new code in our actual packages. This is typically things like backing up db. Post-implementation will deal with issues that need to be addressed after we've deployed the new code - example operation would be to go and modify older data because for instance we've changed a type of column in a table. Checks are just validations performed to make sure the release is 100% correctly implemented - for instance run a select query and assert on the type of data in the column, whose type we've just changed. Today all of these are daunting manual operations performed by whoever is unlucky to be doing a release. Above all else though, being manual these are by definition error prone.

The approach taken is that for every JIRA ticket being part of the release the responsible developer will have to decide what steps (if any) are needed to release their work, and script that. Puppet is supposed to orchestrate the execution of all of this.

Comment: This is very likely the wrong approach to the problem, but it is unclear what you are trying to achieve here. This does also sound like something that would be solved easier with Puppet tasks/plans once you upgrade. In general Puppet < 4.10 is something people used years ago, so your results may vary.

Comment: The problem is that the upgrade to puppet 5.x is beyond my control - it's another team handling this stuff in a huge organisation, so I have no influence over that and I'm stuck on 3.7 for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Can you share a little bit of the manifest(s) that you're working on currently? I've contributed to my fair share of Rube Goldberg machines toward working around legacy installations of Puppet. Also, I'm curious... you suggested this isn't a typical rdbms, but I'm assuming these are essentially migrations you're running. How are you backing out of bad migrations?